# How to disable navigation using UniversalAction

Tags: gmail-addons

I am building an Add-on with a Logout button.
This Log out button is an Universal Action.
As far I was able to do, this is the binded function to this button:

```
function logout(e) {
  ...
  resetOAuth();

  return CardService
      .newUniversalActionResponseBuilder()
      .displayAddOnCards([buildAddOn(e)])
      .build();
}
```

The problem with this is that the new card renders a navigation. So, a "back button" shows on screen.
I wasn't able to make this in a different way. As far I could check, the Trello Add-on and so many others Add-ons renders a simple card when Logout is applied, without the "back" button navigation on.

What else should I need to try?
How can I avoid the navigation on an Universal Action?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CardAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action) instead of a UniversalAction, this way you'll be able to avoid a back button:

```js
function sidebarTrigger () {
  return isUserLoggedIn() ?  renderProfile() : loginCard()
}


function renderProfile() {
  const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()

  // build the card as wished
  // ...

  const logoutAction = CardService.newCardAction()
    .setText('Log out')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('logoutUser'))

  card.addCardAction(logoutAction)

  return card.build()
}

function logoutUser() {
  // your logout logic
  // ...

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(sidebarTrigger()))
    .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot, the only card that has no "back button" is the root card, so maybe you need to change your way to do this.
For me, the best way is to have a init function that looks if we are connected, in this case, you return a card and if we log out so you return another card.